# Creating a for loop that loops over and over =

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

So I have a weird problem (as I can do this using dummy code, but cannot make it work in my actual code) -

The concept is simple - I need a for loop that upon hitting its max "I" number reverts "I" to 0 again and creates a loop over and over -

DUMMY CODE:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
console.log(i);
if(i === 10){
i = 0
}
}
```

Now for the longer code (sorry)

```
    function reviewF(){

  // add ID to each of the objects 

reviews.forEach((e, i)=>{
    e.id = i
})


    // get the elements to be populated on page
    var name = document.querySelector('p.name');
    var date = document.querySelector('p.date');
    var rating = document.querySelector('.rating_stars');

    var review = document.querySelector('p.review_content_text');

    // reverse the array - so the newest reviews are shown first (this is due to how the reviews where downloaded)
    var reviewBack = reviews.slice(0).reverse();



    // start the loop - go over each array - take its details and apply it to the elements

    /**
     * THIS IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO LOOP OVER FOREVER 
     * 
     * **/ 
    for (let i = 0; i < reviewBack.length; i++) {


      (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
        // document.getElementById('reviews').classList.remove('slideOut')
        name.classList.remove('slideOut')
        date.classList.remove('slideOut')
        rating.classList.remove('slideOut')
        review.classList.remove('slideOut')
        name.classList.add('slideIn')
        date.classList.add('slideIn')
        rating.classList.add('slideIn')
        review.classList.add('slideIn')


            name.innerHTML = reviewBack[i].aditional_info_name;
            date.innerHTML = reviewBack[i].Date;
            rating.innerHTML = '';
            review.innerHTML = reviewBack[i].aditional_info_short_testimonial;
            if(reviewBack[i].aditional_info_short_testimonial === 'none'){
                reviewBack.innerHTML='';
            } 

            var numberOfStars = reviewBack[i].aditional_info_rating;

            for(i=0;i<numberOfStars;i++){
                var star = document.createElement('p');
                star.className="stars";
                rating.appendChild(star);
            }


            setTimeout(function(){
                // document.getElementById('reviews').classList.add('slideOut')
                name.classList.add('slideOut')
                 date.classList.add('slideOut')
                 rating.classList.add('slideOut')
                 review.classList.add('slideOut')
            },9600)
        }, i * 10000)
      })(i);
      // should create a infinite loop
    }
    console.log('Loop A')
  }


  // both functions are running as they should but the time out function for the delay of the transition is not?

  reviewF();
```

EDITS >>>>>>>>

Ok so I have found a hack and slash way to fix the issue - but its not dry code and not good code but it works.....

this might make the desiered effect easier to understand

```
reviewF(); // <<< this is the init function

  // this init2 function for the reviews waits until the reviews have run then 
  // calls it again
  setTimeout(function(){
    reviewF();
  }, reviews.length*1000)
  // this version of the innit doubles the number of reviews and calls it after that amount of time
  setTimeout(function(){
    reviewF();
  }, (reviews.length*2)*1000)
```

From trying a bunch of different methods to solve this issue something I noticed was when I placed a console.log('Finished') at the end of the function and called it twice in a row (trying to stack the functions running..... yes I know a horrid and blunt way to try and solve the issue but I had gotten to that point) - it called by console.log's while the function was still running (i.e. the set time out section had not finished) - could this have something to do with it.

My apologies for the rough code.

Any help here would be really great as my own attempts to solve this have fallen short and I believe I might have missed something in how the code runs?

Warm regards, 
W

Comment: In your dummy code, `for(i=0;i<10;i++){` ends as soon as `i` becomes 10, before the test for `if(i === 10){` is reached. Perhaps you meant to test `if (i === 9) {`?

Comment: Hi Shadow - thats correct and yes - it would be / in the actual code however this is based on a Var which is the length of an array which is running backwards (thiss is due to the array length changing over time) so it would be for(i=0;i<reviewBack.length;i++) and would be based on the idea of once i becomes arrya length, make i = 0. I think the issue might acutally lie in the set timeout (that the function runs over and over till it crashes) but the set timeout function doesn't catch up or show the resolts (any input is greatly aprichaited thanks for reaching out)

Comment: Your loop isn't running backwards. And the loop will only set `i` to the array length the instant before the loop condition fails and the loop exits. As for why `setTimeout` never executes, it doesn't look like you ever release control to the event loop; JavaScript isn't threaded, `setTimeout` *can't* execute unless the running code ends or otherwise returns control to the event loop (with `await`, `Promise` related stuff, etc.).

Comment: HI Shadow - I've done some de-bugging off what you said - and I think the approach Ive taken to this code is wrong or the question is wrong for the solution needed - instead - what would be the way to make the above function to run its entirety before being run again - i just tried this with a setTimeOut() but it was not sucsesful - any input would be great

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply nest this for loop inside a [do/while](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_dowhile.asp)?

```
var looping = True
do {
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        console.log(i);
    }

    if (someEndCondition) {
         looping = False;
    }
}
while (looping);
```

Comment: Why bother with the variable? As written, a simple infinite loop with a `break` would work identically.

Comment: It would totally work. Sometimes in deeper nests of conditions, the variable helps me identify which loop I'm breaking out of.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that resetting your loop would be as simple as setting "i = 0" like in the dummy code. So try putting the following into your code at the end of the for loop:

```
    if(i === 10){
     i = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Kyle - Thank you for the reply - this has been something I have already tried but would not work, I believe possibly due to the code blocks? thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I'm not too sure really. You could try removing all parts of the head: so it would be "for(;;){// Code here}. I think that makes a loop infinite.

Comment: HI Kyle - I believe from what I have read that would make it infinite but then there would be no way to know at which array item you are at and once hitting the array.item.length to reset the loop again to 0 and start again. If you have any more info on achiving that, that would be amazing

Comment: In that case, we're back to an if statement again, have you tried placing the if statement at different places within the loop? The obvious place to me seems to be where you have the comment "//should create a infinite loop". Also you could try 'if(i === array.item.length){i = 0;}, but other than that I'm out of ideas I'm afraid, sorry!

Comment: Hi Kyle - that doesn't seem to the be the issue at hand after doing some digging on the code above (not the dummy code) - it would apear that the function is being run and can be run on a infinite loop but as the setTimeout function is running behind the rest of the code there is a lag - now Im trying to make one function run enterly before it either looping or the function running again (<<<< this is all based on an "I think thats whats happening") - thanks again

Comment: Ah I see, it sounds like you need something similar to what @ShadowRanger said about 'Await' or 'promises'. However, I'm still learning about these so I don't think I'll be able to help you any further with that as I don't want to be spreading any misinformation!